# can i store images loaded by user in mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a multiplex booking project in java.For this i have asked user to load the image of movie through browse button .so, my question is can i store the images loaded by user on user interface to database .i am using mysql query browser.

Comment: You can store images in the database. However, storing them as files instead of database would be better. If you store the images in database then your database will probably grow huge if there are lot of images uploaded.

Comment: @virendra i just want that corresponding to image selected by user movie details get displayed by itself .is that possible by other ways if i dont store movie picture in database.

Answer (score 0):

Storing images in database is not a right option. There are more disadvantages than advantages. Images are files, do not store files in database. Database is to store data.

You should think about storing images in directory structure for users if the images are going to be large in future.

Comment: i just want if a user selects a image then corresponding movie name, director etc get displayed by itseif corresponding to movie image displayed .that is possible only if i store image in database.